# Custom TextField With Caption

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I am developing an IPhone application and trying to create a custom TextField with caption on it like image below.[image]

As you can see from image Label is changed by the value that user enters or read from database. Also there are other textfields other than name.

I couldn't be sure how should i implement this custom textfield?

One way i think placing an image with "Name:" text to background of textfield and placing "Label" value on it, other way is placing an image with only borders and inserting "Name:    Label" text on it.

Are these ways suitable or is there any other best approach available?

Edit: Borders on image are textfield's border; also "Name:    Label" is above on textfield.

Comment: Have you looked at UITextField's placeholder property?

Comment: yes but placeholder text disappears when text is set.

Comment: but this is the idea of the placeholder: as long as the textfield is empty, the placeholder holds it's place.

Comment: you are right; but i want to display placeholder as textfields label, only not at the left side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put another label with the desired text behind or beside the label or text field that is going to be filled. You can set the `font` and `textColor` and even the `alpha` according to your taste.

Make sure that if they overlap (which they should not!) the `backgroundColor` property of the label is set to `[UIColor clearColor]`.

You could subclass `UITextField` like this:

```
@interface LabeledTextField : UIView
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *textField;
@end


#define kPercentWidth 0.5
@implementation LabeledTextField
-initWithCoder:(NSCoder)aDecoder {
   self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
   if (self) {
      CGRect f = self.frame;
      _label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,
               f.size.width*kPercentWidth,f.size.height)];
      _textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,
               f.size.width*(1-kPercentWidth),f.size.height)];
      [self addSubView:_label]; 
      [self addSubView:_textField];
   }
   return self;
}
@end
```

You could then use it like this: insert a `UIView` into your storyboard view controller and change the class to your `LabeledTextField`. This would ensure `initWithCoder` is called. Otherwise, you might have to put the init code into its own `setup` function and call it from your override of `initWithFrame`. Make sure you wire up the view with your outlet

```
// .h
#include LabeledTextField.h
//...
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet LabeledTextField *labeledTextField;

// .m, in some method
labeledTextField.textField.text = @"editable text";
labeledTextField.label.text = @"non-editable text";
```

Similarly, you could modify all properties of the label and text field, including colors, fonts etc.

Comment: is this the best approach? i assume we should create a custom textfield control that contains two text properties one for label and one for value.

Comment: You would have to create a custom UIView that contains a label and a text field as in my solution above, as subviews.

Comment: hmm, now it seems nice ;) i am not very professional at ios development, so could you share a tutorial with me? i couldn't find right one; all of them that i found contains same content; using an image as background of textfield not creating customized textfield.

Comment: I think my answer is correct. It includes even a solution to your follow-up question.

Comment: Yes, it seems ok but i need some more detail to apply and check is your solution suits my requirements. So i asked, could you please share an article with me, i couldn't find.

Comment: No, I usually read Apple's documentation, there is everything I need. If you need help with subclassing a `UIView` maybe you want to ask a new question. Your original question is answered. You should also try to put some effort into it yourself. As an exception, I will suggest some code, but you should upvote my answer also.